# Calculate $(n+k)^{e} \mod m$ based on $(n)^{e} \mod m$ (without knowledge $n$)

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Is there any way to calculate:

$(n+k)^{e} \mod m$

based on result:

$n^{e} \mod m$

?

I'm not looking for a perfect solution.

I know only the result of $n^{e} \mod m$

- I do not know the specific basis $n$.

I want to base $n$ (I do not know her) to add $k$ and get the result of modular power.

Is that possible?

I would be grateful for any hints.

Edit: All integer values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not work for $e$ even power, since for any $m>2$, $2|\phi(m)$ there is at least 2 numbers $n_1,n_2$ such that $n_1^e = n_2^e \mod m$ yet $(n_1+k)^e \not = (n_2+k)^e \mod m$.

For instance let $e=4,k=5,m=35$ and $n^4 \mod 35 = 11$ so what $n$ you choose ?

because $n_1=3,n_2=4 ,\cdots$ and $(3+5)^4 \not = (4+5)^4 \not= \cdots \mod 35$.

or even if $e| \phi(m)$ for instance $n_1=4,n_2=29,e=3,k=3,m=35,n^e \mod 35 = 29$.

Assuming that $e \not| \phi(m)$ you will have unique $n^e \mod m$ but i don't think it will give you any hint about the value of $(n+k)^e \mod m$, unless you know $e$ and $\phi(m)$ even if you don't know $n$ but you still know $n^e \mod m$ you can run Tonelli–Shanks Generalized algorithm to find $n$, and then just add to it $k$ and find out what is $(n+k)^e \mod m$.

You just need to do factorization, for instance $e=5,m=35,k=3,n^e \mod m= 17$

i need to find $n$ from $n^e \mod m$ and $e$ and the factorization of $m$

for small values you can use Wolfram to get that $n=12$ and you are done.

So basically what the argument shows is for **prime powers** its easy work, for big composite number **just forget about it**